# How to implement 'Open in app' button to open same link in the Android app?

Tags: android

I need to add 'Open in app' button in website in small screen to link with the same Android application. For example: when we share any twitter profile in facebook, and open it in facebook it opens in browser with 'Open in app' button. And when we click on that 'Open in app' button it directs to Twitter app with same Profile. That's it. How do i get it?
[I have attached Screenshot so you will be more clear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ62g.png)

[image]

Comment: your web page is written in which language?

Comment: HTML, CSS, PHP, Jquery

Answer (score 4):

Following code will help you to open installed android app from browser:

```
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=appName package=<your package of android application>;end">Open in App</a>
```

Happy Coding !!!